# How to display multiple Countdown timer in php

Tags: javascript, php, timer

Firtly, i select all data time from database, but when show to the page only the first one items will show the timer, other items cannot to show the timer.

```
 <?php
     $stmtAuction = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM auction WHERE expired_at >= CURDATE() AND status = 'available' ORDER BY expired_at ASC");
                    $stmtAuction->execute();
     if ($stmtAuction->rowCount() > 0) {
                        while ($item = $stmtAuction->fetch()) {
       ?>
          <span id='countdown' value='<?php echo $item['expired_at'];?>'></span>       

<?php
}
?>
    <script>

     $("#countdown").countdown($('#countdown').attr('value'), function(event) {
                $(this).text(
                    event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
                );
            });
    </script>
```

how can  i show timer for every items??

Comment: Well you have `$stmtAuction->rowCount()` number of `id='countdown'`. `id`s are supposed to be unique. So javascript/jQuery will only find the 1st/unique `id='countdown'`. You need to use `class='countdown'`, and `$(".countdown")`, although you will need to make some additional changes to make this work.

Comment: it works...but all the timer display same time and date

Comment: how can i display timer based on my database select?

Comment: Have added an answer that shows changing from `id` to `class`, as well as how to use `$(".countdown")`  and `$.each()` to display each timer data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by un-unique `id`s. You have `$stmtAuction->rowCount()` number of `id='countdown'`. `id`s are supposed to be unique. So javascript/jQuery will only find the 1st/unique `id='countdown'`. You need to use `class='countdown'` instead -

```
<?php
    $stmtAuction = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM auction WHERE expired_at >= CURDATE() AND status = 'available' ORDER BY expired_at ASC");
    $stmtAuction->execute();
    if ($stmtAuction->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($item = $stmtAuction->fetch()) {
        ?>
            <span class='countdown' value='<?php echo $item['expired_at'];?>'></span>
                  ^^^^^-change from id to class
<?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Now in your javascript, you need to use the class selector -  `$(".countdown")` - and loop over each class using `$.each()`.

```
<script>
    $('.countdown').each(function(){
        $(this).countdown($(this).attr('value'), function(event) {
            $(this).text(
                event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

a [jsFiddle example - https://jsfiddle.net/smh5nhgz/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/smh5nhgz/1/)

Comment: hi sean , why when i put today date for example , `value='2016/01/05 05:00:00'` , then the countdown become 00 days 00:00:00...how to fix it?